# EF DbSet.Find() returns Detached Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I have a very simple `Entity` with just 4 fields: Name, State, City and ID and some Validations.

```
[Table("Places")]
public class Place : BindableBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string name;
    private string city;
    private Estado state;
    private int id;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]        
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref name, value); }
    }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string City
    {
        get { return this.city; }
        set { SetProperty(ref city, value); }
    }

    [Required]        
    public State State
    {
        get { return this.state; }
        set { SetProperty(ref state, value); }
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return this.id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref id, value); }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get 
        {
            return Validator.TryValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this), new Collection<ValidationResult>(), true);
        }
    }

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members
    /// <summary>
    /// IDataErrorInfo Interface Error Message for the object.
    /// </summary>
    [NotMapped]
    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get 
        {
            var context = new ValidationContext(this)
            {
                MemberName = propertyName
            };

            var results = new Collection<ValidationResult>();
            bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(this, context, results, true);

            if (!isValid)
            {
                ValidationResult result = results.SingleOrDefault(p =>
                                                                  p.MemberNames.Any(memberName =>
                                                                                    memberName == propertyName));

                return result == null ? null : result.ErrorMessage;
            }

            return null; 
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I can add it to the DB just fine, but once I try to update it, I get an Exception.

I am using:

```
public void UpdatePlace(Place place)
{
    var entity = context.Places.Find(place.Id);

    if (entity == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Place not found.");
    }

    context.Entry(place).CurrentValues.SetValues(place);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I get to

```
context.Entry(place).CurrentValues.SetValues(place);
```

I get an Exception as:

> System.InvalidOperationException
>
> "Member 'CurrentValues' cannot be called for the entity of type
>   'Place' because the entity does not exist in the context.
>   To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of
>   DbSet."

`context.Entry` shows me that indeed the entity is detached

[image: context.Entry shows detached]

But `DbSet.Find()` method's documentation shows clearly that `Find()` should return an attached entity in case one is found in the DB:

> Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store. Otherwise, a request is made to the store for an entity with the given primary key values and this **entity, if found, is attached to the context and returned**. If no entity is found in the context or the store, then null is returned.

So when I try to get `CurrentValues`, since the entity is detached, it throws the `Exception`... but as far as I can see, there should be an attached entity, or null, not anything else....

I can't find anything about this error online, I am using SQL CE 4.0 as the DB, does anyone knows what's happening?

I think I can just `Attach` the entity every time I get it from `Find` but still I want to understand what's going on with my software, since this shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should just change this line to:

```
  context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(place);
```

Comment: Ok...now I feel dumb hahaha, I got this code from a tutorial, I should have had paid more attention on the copy+paste, and the tutorial is completely wrong, I will notify the author. Many thanks ErikEJ! 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SwgqLJCLI8
the code shows on 6:30 of the video.

Comment: 4:00 minutes actually.

Comment: Just to add, he did made unit tests, so apparently this code was "trusted"....I guess this turns to be a great lesson about tests....